# How to exclude dnsmasq used by libvirt from Mullvad VPN's "local network sharing" block

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall, dnsmasq, nftables

I don't use the local network except dnsmasq for libvirt. With blocking local network I have no DNS on my VM. For that reason I want to exclude dnsmasq from the local network sharing block with split tunneling using this guide: `https://mullvad.net/en/help/split-tunneling-with-linux-advanced`.

As far as I understood, in my case dnsmasq isn't resolving the DNS of my host machine but only the DNS of specific NIC (VM one). Information about libvirt dnsmasq `https://www.whonix.org/wiki/KVM#DHCP`

I want to disable local network sharing for maximum security, but allow dnsmasq using the netfilter rules from the Mullvad guide, WITHOUT opening the port for other computers/router on my local network.

The only local connection I need to work is dnsmasq

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      dnsmasq
```

Comment: expect or except?